# html css menu not working properly

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a menu and I include this in every page. In this page, the book & allocate menu bar is working properly when I move my mouse over it but search and add menu bar not working properly. when I move the mouse over the menu bar it doesnt show the submenu but when I mover the mouse over text it shows the submenu and when I try to go to submenu it disappears.

MENU CODE

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="UserLogged.jsp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ADMIN</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">ADD</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">ADD DRIVER</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ADD EMPLOYEE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ADD VEHICLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ADD VENDOR</a></li>
         <li><a href="">ADD MAINTENANCE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a>
    <ul><li><a href="ActionServlet?actionName=searchBooking">Booking</a></li>
        <li><a href="ActionServlet?actionName=searchDriver">Driver</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Employee</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vendor</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Maintenance</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">BOOK & ALLOCATE</a>
    <ul><li><a href="">BOOK VEHICLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ALLOCATE VEHICLE</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="LogoutController?actionName=logOut">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

MENU CSS CODE

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: garamond;


}
ul li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul a {

    display: block;
    width: 152px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    padding: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: left;


}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}

ul li ul{

    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 188px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;

}

ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    margin-left:160px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: left;
    padding : 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;


}

ul li ul a{
    text-align: center;

}
```

MY PAGE CODE

```
<body>
<% if (session.getAttribute("username")==null) { 
      out.println("Please login first");
   } else { %>
    <%@include file="include/header.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="include/menu.jsp" %>
    <%@include file="include/sideimage.jsp" %>

<form name="addDriver" method="post" action="AddDriverVehicleController?op=1">
<div id="addDriver">
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Driver Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dName" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Driver Address</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="dAddress" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>City</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="dCity" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Contact No</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="dContact" required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
   <td>Country</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="dCountry" required>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
   <td align="right"><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>

<%} %>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your code to jsfiddle.net or similar site, it will be easier for people to help you

Comment: I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f986azod/) and it seems to work fine for me (all the hovering seems to work fine for each menu and submenu item)

Comment: @zgood - Yes it is working fine if u dont align the table on the centre. If u keep the table at the bottom it will not work properly.

Comment: @VaibhavDalela I think then we need more css from your project to fix it. Could you update that fiddle with the css and markup needed to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @zgood - I have added the table css in the fiddle. please check here is the link. https://jsfiddle.net/yww028w7/2/ plz help me out I am student I have to submit my internship project with in two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this style to your `<form>`:

```
form{   
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yww028w7/3/).

Your `#addDriver` style has a `margin-left:490px;` and because it's a `block` element it is interferring with your menu hovering (it's overlapping).

It would be a good idea to look into a css grid framework like Bootstrap, which can help you layout your site on a grid without having these overlapping problems.